# Gridview radiobutton templatefield only one chosen-javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a `Gridview` with a `Radiobutton Itemtemplate`. I want to group the entire column and only one `Radiobutton` should be chosen.
But I don't want to do a `postback` to check them in server side. Is it possible to done with javascript ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use HTML radio button with `name` property to group all radio buttons in GridView's `ItemTemplate`:

```
<input type="radio" id="TheId" name="GroupName" />
```

OR

If you don't want to use HTML radio buttons then you need to handle the `checked` property for radio buttons yourself by using javascript/jQuery as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627634/using-radiobuttons-in-a-gridview-control).

Comment: i am talking about templatefield in gridview